# Having trouble inserting columns - not enough memory

Tags: excel, memory, vba

I'm currently working on a macro that will format results from a questionnaire we run to feed into a dashboard.

I need to insert columns into the spreadsheet, but only after specific questions. I'm using the code below to insert the columns, but when it gets to the part to insert columns, I get an error saying "Not enough memory" and Excel will shut down.

I currently have 485 columns and 1534 rows (it's respondent level data with multi-coded questions).

```
Sub AddingFillerColumns()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim FCol As Long
    Dim xRange As Range

    Workbooks("WaveData.xlsx").Activate

    FCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For x = 214 To FCol Step 29
        If Cells(1, x).Value Like "Q9*" Then
            Set xRange = Cells(1, x)
                Range(xRange.End(xlDown), xRange).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                Cells(1, x).Value = "Q9_None"
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get you code to fail on me.
Maybe just insert the columns instead of setting xrange and determining the range to insert.

```
Sub AddingFillerColumns()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim FCol As Long

    'Workbooks("WaveData.xlsx").Activate

    FCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For x = 214 To FCol Step 29
        If Cells(1, x).Value Like "Q9*" Then
            Cells(1, x).EntireColumn.Insert
            Cells(1, x) = "Q9_None"
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Are there lots of formulas?

Comment: No at all - there's just a lot of data (or at least I think there is) in the table itself.